# CSS styling a child element from a parent element using selectors

Tags: css, angular

Suppose I have 3 levels of HTML tag elements in a parent child relationship. A  is a grandparent. Inside that  there is a  tag(parent) and inside that  tag there is a

tag(child).Now by using CSS I want to change the design of that

(child) tag from the (grandparent) tag using CSS selectors from that (grandparent) id or class name.

Need help on this css trick

```
<div>
   Hi I am grandparent.
     <h2>
        Hi I am parent.
          <p> Hi I am child. </p>
     </h2>
     <h2>
        Hi I am parent.
          <p> Hi I am child. </p>
     </h2>
     <h2>
        Hi I am parent.
          <p> Hi I am child. </p>
     </h2>
     <h2>
        Hi I am parent.
          <p> Hi I am child. </p>
     </h2>
     <h2>
        Hi I am parent.
          <p> Hi I am child. </p>
     </h2>
</div>
```

I want the result to be as follows:
Make the background color of the

tag to any colour only for the 4th  parent.
Note that the control should be from the  grandparent.
This is because I have a *ngfor in the  grandparent and I want to write the css for that  using nth-child(n) concept.

Comment: Where's the CSS that you've tried for your problem? It seems you already know that the solution requires `nth-child(n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :nth-child() property of CSS! Try below-given code. I'm also attaching the link for working CodePen. To understand how it works you can play with it!

Visit the pen for more understanding and live demo: https://codepen.io/CUManiar/pen/vqGdze

```css
.grand-parent {
  color: blue;
}

.grand-parent h2:nth-child(4) {
  color: red;
}

.grand-parent .parent p:nth-child(2) {
  color: pink
}
```

```html
<div class="grand-parent">
   Hi I am grandparent.
     <h2 class="parent">
        Hi I am parent.
          <p class="child"> Hi I am grand child. </p>
          <p class="child"> Hi I am 2nd grand child. </p>
     </h2>
     <h2 class="parent">
        Hi I am parent.
          <p class="child"> Hi I am 2nd child. </p>
     </h2>
     <h2 class="parent">
        Hi I am parent.
          <p class="child"> Hi I am 3rd child. </p>
     </h2>
     <h2 class="parent">
        Hi I am parent.
          <p class="child"> Hi I am 4th child. </p>
     </h2>
     <h2 class="parent">
        Hi I am parent.
          <p class="child"> Hi I am 5th child. </p>
     </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Although your `h2` tags shouldn't contain `p` tags, this ought to do the trick:

```
div h2:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```css
    div h2:nth-of-type(4) {
      background-color: tomato;
    }
```

```html
<div>
   Hi I am grandparent.
     <h2>
        Hi I am parent.
          <p> Hi I am child. </p>
     </h2>
     <h2>
        Hi I am parent.
          <p> Hi I am child. </p>
     </h2>
     <h2>
        Hi I am parent.
          <p> Hi I am child. </p>
     </h2>
     <h2>
        Hi I am parent.
          <p> Hi I am child. </p>
     </h2>
     <h2>
        Hi I am parent.
          <p> Hi I am child. </p>
     </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: `nth-of-type(4)` isn't the pseudo class that'll work here. Did you even run the snippet before posting your answer?

Comment: My bad, did not scroll down